# Empty string variable matching to LIKE conditions in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

I have a SQL Server table containing a `nvarchar(max)` column. I ran a query to select every row where this column contains the string 'remove'. Amongst the results, I have several rows where this column is populated with an empty string and I don't understand why these values have been returned.

I tried to investigate further, on one of the empty string values returned. I found that the empty string value would match to certain `LIKE` conditions, but not others. For instance, it will match to `%remove%` and `%x%`, but it won't match to `%q%`.

Within the results grid on SQL Server Management Studio, the nvarchar field is displayed as an empty field (it is not null). However, if I apply the `len()` function to this field, it returns the value of 649. When I export the results table from SQL Server Management Studio into Excel, the `nvarchar(max)` field is empty.

Assuming that there must be a bunch of whitespace characters populating the field, I tried to select the field after concatenating 'x' to either end of the value returned. In the results, the leading 'x' appears at the beginning of the string, but the 'x' concatenated onto the end is not displayed.

I'm totally confused as to what is going on. I can provide more information upon request.

```
select itemid, content
from objects
where itemid = 100 and content like '%remove%'

----------------


itemid  |  content
100     |
```

---

```
select itemid, 'x' + content + 'x' as 'content'
from objects
where itemid = 100 and content like '%remove%'

----------------


itemid  |  content
100     |  x
```

**EDIT:**

Trimming the field doesn't change the character count. However, when I do use substring to select the last character in the concatenated output, the character returned is 'x', which suggests that it just isn't visible in the GUI output due to the length of the string. I still can't see this trailing 'x' character when exporting the content into Excel though. I think that there are maybe unsupported characters present within the nvarchar variable.

---

```
select itemid, 'x' + ltrim(rtrim(content)) + 'x' as 'content'
from objects
where itemid = 100 and content like '%remove%'

----------------


itemid  |  content
100     |  x
```

Comment: I can't reproduce, did you really test in the exact same condition ?

Comment: I [can't reproduce this behavior](http://rextester.com/GQUP34325).  Can you provide a reproducible sample?

Comment: Have you tried using LTRIM() on your field? This will remove any leading spaces from the left side of the string. You could also look to analyze LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(content))) and that will remove leading or trailing spaces and give you the length.

Comment: As others mentioned, the column may be full of spaces (or other non-displayable characters) rather than actually empty. Hard to tell by looking, but the length value is a big giveaway. Depending how wide you're displaying the column in your GUI it may not be obvious that later in the field it contains the value you searched for. Maybe paste the result into a text editor such as Notepad++ and you can see the whole thing and you'll see easily if there are spaces, tabs etc in there.

Comment: Something seems amiss by your second query, specifically `'x' + content + 'x'`. The result, according to your output is `x`. This can't be the case. `'x' + '' + 'x'` would result in `xx`. `'x' + '    ' + 'x'` would result in `'x    x'`. And lastly, `'x' + NULL + 'x'` would result in `NULL` I have a feeling that that other x is in your output, but you've not scrolled way enough over the the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you have some control character(s) in the string.  If the first character is a newline, for example, that may cause the rest not to be displayed.

Try

```
select item_id, unicode(content) 
from objects
where item_id = 100;
```

This will show the unicode code point for the first character you can see the second character with:

```
unicode(substring(item, 2, 1))
```

and so on.

Comment: I think that you might be correct about what's causing this.

I have run the unicode function across every character of the string value returned and it has shown unicode values ranging from 0 to 121.

I don't know much about unicode characters and their compatibility in this context. Does what I've observed confirm that there are unsupported characters in the string or do you need me to provide further information?

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8 or http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl, or http://www.thedatastudio.net/character_encoding_profile.htm to find out what the Unicode code points are.  The lower values (U+0000 thru U+001F) are control characters so invisible but cause havoc with the display.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should trim the column;

```
select itemid, LTRIM(RTRIM(content))
from objects
where itemid = 100 and content like '%remove%'
```