# escape special character in a report

Tags: sql, reporting-services, report, dynamics-crm

Am creating a report (ssrs-sql) and then deploying the report to Dynamics CRM.
When exporting the report to a txtfile I had some extra quotes for one column and only for some records.

I examined those records and find out that they contain some special characters but I cannot identify which one. How to identify the special characters & how to escape it when exporting to .txt(ASCII)?

Example of my record:

```
<result>
<name>New York 
<name>
<createdon date="20/12/2017" time="16:09">2017-12-20T16:09:53+02:00</createdon>
     </result>
```

The problem is on the name column.

Comment: Have a look at the accepted answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47715714/empty-string-variable-matching-to-like-conditions-in-sql/47716024#47716024.  I think that might help you.

Comment: Thank you Ron , you saved my week.