# Error Code: 1300. Invalid utf8 character string:

Tags: sql, utf-8

I came across a similar question but it didn't answer my question.  I'm using the following script to load data:

```
LOAD DATA local INFILE 'C:/Users/david.trautvetter/Desktop/SQL Files/Bookings FY18 Q1 - Strategic Accounts.csv' INTO TABLE david.bookingsfy18q1_sa
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
  IGNORE 1 LINES
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Error Code: 1300. Invalid utf8 character string: 'NESTL'
```

I assumed the offending character was É, but when I checked the record it was NESTL DEUTSCHLAND AG, no diacritic.  I tried using IGNORE LOAD DATA but that didn't work.

Suggestions?  Thanks, David

Comment: I added the very general `sql` tag, but you might want to use a more specific one to get attention from the right people.

Comment: Have a look at the accepted answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47715714/empty-string-variable-matching-to-like-conditions-in-sql/47716024?noredirect=1#comment82393038_47716024.  This is also about finding dodgy characters and working out what they are.  There are a couple of useful reference links there too.

Comment: Thanks Ron, now I'm trying to load another table and am getting the error code 1300 for a record that doesn't even exist in the data set...this is driving me nutso...